# Sum of squares prime power

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume $n>1$ is a positive integer. Assume n can uniquely be written as a sum of squared rationals $x^2+y^2$ with $x>y$, $(x,y)=1$, and one of $x$ or $y$ is even. Prove $n$ is a prime power.

I tried using the fact that one must be odd to find out about $n$, but this got me no where.

Comment: A natural $n$ can be written in the form of sum of two squares if and only if $m$ has no prime divisor of the form $4k+3$ where $m$ is the square free part of $n$. Using  this theorem, it should be easy to show this.

Comment: What is an even or odd rational? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I think the OP must mean 'squared, strictly positive integers'.

Comment: Do you know the [Fermat two squares theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat's_Two_Squares_Theorem) ? Do you know that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a unique factorization domain ?